# How to modify layouts in SP 2013 (cloud version)

Tags: page-layout

I am new to this forum and looking for information about how to create or modify SharePoint layouts in 2013. I have searched the web for a full day. Found a lot of information and instruction but none of it makes sense in the version of SharePoint I am using. I am not new to SP but new to creating master pages.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!
Henry

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: - Design a good master page, i.e. an HTML page.
1.) You need to create a HTML page and then convert it into a master page(from design  manager). follow link below for reference:

[Designing Master Pages](http://blog.navantis.com/creating-a-new-master-page-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Step 2: - follow this link for example on layouts which you will have to make for a master page: - 
[Designing page layouts](http://blog.navantis.com/create-a-custom-page-layout-in-sharepoint-2013/)